# PrivateRouting when Token in Local Storage [TypeScript]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, apollo

If my login in successful, an authentication token is returned, which is stored in the local storage. Upon successful login, I want to go the a private route.

I found this code Javascript snippet but I am unable to make it work for Typescript. I don't have any isAuthenthicated property yet. How could I modify this accordingly?

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location }
   }}/>
  )
 )}/>
)
```

Here is my login screen:

```
const LoginMutation = gql`
mutation LoginMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
  loginEmail(email: $email, password: $password)
}
`;

const schema = Yup.object({
  email: Yup
    .string()
    .email('Invalid Email')
    .required('Please Enter your Email'),
  password: Yup
    .string()
    .required('Please Enter your password')
});

function LoginPage (){
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    loggedIn: false,
  });  


  function submitForm(LoginMutation: any) {
    const { email, password } = state;
    console.log(email, password)
    if(email && password){
      LoginMutation({
        variables: {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        },
    }).then(({ data }: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.loginEmail);
    })
    .catch(console.log)

    }
  }

    return (
      <Mutation mutation={LoginMutation}>
        {(LoginMutation: any) => (
              <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                Sign in
              </Typography>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: '', password: '' }}
                onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    actions.setSubmitting(false);
                  }, 1000);
                }}
                validationSchema={schema}
              >
                {props => {
                  const {
                    values: { email, password },
                    errors,
                    touched,
                    handleChange,
                    isValid,
                    setFieldTouched
                  } = props;
                  const change = (name: string, e: any) => {
                    e.persist();                
                    handleChange(e);
                    setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
                    setState( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   [name]: e.target.value }));  
                  };
                  return (
                    <form style={{ width: '100%' }} onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault();submitForm(LoginMutation)}}>
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        id="email"
                        fullWidth
                        name="email"
                        helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ""}
                        error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                        label="Email"     
                        value={email}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "email")}
                      />
                      <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        fullWidth
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        helperText={touched.password ? errors.password : ""}
                        error={touched.password && Boolean(errors.password)}
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        value={password}
                        onChange={change.bind(null, "password")}
                      />
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                      />
                      <br />
                      <Button className='button-center'
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={!isValid || !email || !password}
                      >
                        Submit</Button>
                    </form>
                  )
                }}
              </Formik>
            </div>
          )
        }
      </Mutation>
    );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

There is a similar question but it doesn't answer my case since I'm storing the token in local storage.

Comment: _How could I modify this accordingly?_ It depends [on how your authentication works]. If existence of token means user is loggen in then, the simplest change is to change `fakeAuth.isAuthenticated` to `localStorage.token`

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of something like: ```const userLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('token');``` But, any idea how I could make this work in typescript? @Max

Comment: In most cases, you should have some sort of a store(Redux, MobX, etc.) to hold 
user's data. Then you just get it from a store and use as you want. What do you mean particularly by "How I could make this work in typescript'?

Comment: Oh yeah, I haven't added Redux yet. I'll add that first. But on the other side, I am basically using grpahql apollo for the authentication. Now apollo itself is a state management library. In this case, how could I use apollo?

Comment: Personally, I don't have the best practices for apollo caching in that case. Because for me, sometimes, it seems unreasonable to use apollo cache in situations that involve data parsing and business logic. These thing should be process and held by a store(or back-end). And authentication might fall into this zone as well. Although, I heard that using stores next to apollo cache is bad practice. But also, 
I've seen some guides where people say that you must use a store and don't rely on apollo cache entirely. So it's all up to you there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will go in your index.tsx file:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

const PrivateRoute = ({component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}: any) => {
    const routeComponent = (props: any) => (
        isAuthenticated
            ? React.createElement(component, props)
            : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login'}}/>
    );
    return <Route {...rest} render={routeComponent}/>;
};
```

And use this in the browser router/switch:

```
<PrivateRoute
    path='/panel'
    isAuthenticated={token}
    component={PrivateContainer}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace fakeAuth.isAuthenticated by your saved token which you might save it also as a global state right? so, in general, it just a boolean prop to check if the user is successfully login or not depend on that situation the user will redirect either to the login page or the protected page